# Change path to help in QGIS 3.4.8 LTR

Tags: qgis, path

I want to use the offical help from qgis, which I can open with the F1 button.
But it doesn´t work. I always get this message:

[image]

I checked the Settings → Options →System, the path is right. And in the .ini is the right URL.

Is there any possibility to set another URL ?

Comment: What is the path mentioned in your settings? The one in my version (3.8.1) uses `https://docs.qgis.org/$qgis_short_version/$qgis_locale/docs/user_manual/`.

Comment: In my version QGIS uses the same path: https://docs.qgis.org/$qgis_short_version/$qgis_locale/docs/user_manual/ but I always get the error message

Answer (score 1):

Use the following path:

```
https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/
```

QGIS automatically appends `/index.html` at the end of the path which should lead you to the correct [web page](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/index.html).

**Edit:**

For the German documentation:

```
https://www.qgis.org/de/docs/
```

Comment: It doesn´t work. Is it possible to use a path to a network drive, for example to open a pdf?

Comment: @joe_gerner - When you click F1 and the webpage opens, what is the web address?

Comment: this is the adress when I click F1 :
file:///C:/Program%20Files/QGIS%203.4/apps/qgis-ltr/doc/nohelp.html

Comment: @joe_gerner - So when you set `https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/` in _Settings > Options_, you still get the address `file:///C:/Program%20Files/QGIS%203.4/apps/qgis-ltr/doc/nohelp.html`?

Comment: @joe_gerner - Edited post to include a link to the German webpage.

Comment: sorry, I don´t understand what you mean

Comment: @joe_gerner - Try using `https://www.qgis.org/de/docs/` in _Settings > Options_.

Comment: It doen´t work. Is it possible to store the help document as PDF file and to link the help (F1) to this local file?

Answer (score 0):

I put the URL in the options, but I always get the error message if I press F1

[image]